# How do I connect to an AWS PostgreSQL RDS instance using SSL and the sslrootcert parameter from a Windows environment?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We have a `Windows EC2` instance on which we are running a custom command line application (C# console app using NpgSQL) to connect to a PostgreSQL RDS instance.  Based on the instructions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

we created a new DB parameter group with `rds.force_ssl set` to `1` and rebooted our RDS instance.  We also downloaded and imported to Windows the pem file referenced on the page.

I was able to connect to the RDS instance from my Windows EC2 instance via pgAdmin by specifying `SSL mode as Verify-Full`.  Our command-line application reads connection strings from a file and they look like this now that I've added the sslmode parameter:

```
Server=OurInstanceAddress;Port=5432;SearchPath='$user,public,topology';Database=OurDatabase;User Id=username;Password=mypassword;sslmode=verify-full;
```

Using this connection string failed with the error referenced at the bottom of the page:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "host.ip", user "someuser", database "postgres", SSL off
```

I tried adding the sslrootcert parameter, but I'm not sure if I'm dealing with it properly.  I tried using the example (sslrootcert=rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem) and I tried using the name of the pem that I downloaded.  I feel like there is something about the path information that I'm giving to the sslrootcert parameter that isn't right, especially in a Windows environment.  I've tried using the name, I've tried using the following paths:

```
- sslrootcert=C:\keys\rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem - single backslash
 - sslrootcert=C:\\\keys\\\rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem - double backslash
 - sslrootcert=C:/keys/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem - Linux style backslash
```

All of these produced the same error mentioned above.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Since I am using Npgsql, I tried my connection string with SSL=true;SslMode=Require; instead of sslmode=verify-full and I still received the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using the environment variables instead for specifiying cert paths in connection url

```
 -DPGSSLROOTCERT=/certs/root.crt 
 -DPGSSLKEY=/certs/amazon-postgresql.key 
 -PGSSLCERT=/certs/amazon-postgresql.crt
```

Although I'm in cygwin. There are some hints in the documentation when using windows here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-ssl.html